# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cuda' has no attribute 'createCannyEdgeDetector'

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, edge-detection

I have been trying to implement image edge detection using cuda in python and for that I was following this [blog](https://medium.com/@heeduugar/canny-edge-detector-in-python-and-opencv-cpu-vs-gpu-with-cuda-229e7bafc5e9).
So after running the code block for 'OPENCV PYTHON CODE USING CPU AND GPU WITH CUDA' I am getting this error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-79c1e18e16f9> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 img = cv.imread('beetle.png',0)
      7 imgMat = cv.cuda_GpuMat(img)
----> 8 detector = cv.cuda.createCannyEdgeDetector(low_thresh=100, high_thresh=110)
      9 dstImg = detector.detect(imgMat)
     10 canny = dstImg.download()

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cuda' has no attribute 'createCannyEdgeDetector'
```

Attaching the code below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from cv2 import cuda
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('beetle.png',0)
imgMat = cv.cuda_GpuMat(img)
detector = cv.cuda.createCannyEdgeDetector(low_thresh=100, high_thresh=110)
dstImg = detector.detect(imgMat)
canny = dstImg.download()
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(canny,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

I tried searching the library where this function exists but there was no way shown how to import this in python

Comment: Is your OpenCV binary built with Cuda support? Have a look at its [build information](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga0ae377100bc03ce22322926bba7fdbb5).

Comment: I tried this on Google Colab. How do I check there?

Comment: python: `print(cv.getBuildInformation())` -- the official packages do not contain cuda. if you need an opencv with cuda, you'll need to build that yourself or get binaries from elsewhere. the packages built by `conda-forge` might contain cuda.

Comment: @Madhura Sawant. It worked for me. Are you using pyCharm?

Comment: @toyotaSupra no. I am using Google Colab